# Generic AGL Exception in Compact Framework and CE7

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a startup process that is throwing some ambiguous errors on a CE7 Device, but not CE6 or Windows Mobile. This is being thrown on the first start of the application after Device startup, but not any subsequent application starts.

I get several of these errors, all in relation to activities pertaining to a menu item.

the code that's executing is pretty basic:

```
Menu.MenuItem[1].enabled = true;

System.Exception: Exception
at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)    
at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem._SetInfo(AGL_MENUITEMINFO& mnueinfo)   
at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.set_Enabled(Boolean value)    
at Plugins.Mail.Form.EnableKeys(Boolean enabled)    
at Plugins.Mail.Mail2.set_KeysEnabled(Boolean value)    
at Plugins.Mail.Mail2.Subscribe()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how anyone can tell you why an error that's only described as "Exception" occurs.

Comment: How is the app starting?  Is the shell full up before your app launches?

Comment: The Shell is completely running by the time the application is started. I'm starting it currently by a shortcut via explorer.

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this in the end? Please post it.

Comment: In the end, I opened up a support ticket with Microsoft, and we ended up identifying an issue in the OS. They ended up issuing a patch to the OS in order to resolve it, but it took 6+ months to get finished. Here's the MS KB Article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2837361